# Top Margin for Tr present in the Table

Tags: javascript, css, html-table

Is there any other way to set the margin(top) for tr present in the Table?.

I have try with the following code snippet:

```
<tr style="margin-top:30px">
    <td style="margin-top:30px">January</td>
    <td style="margin-top:30px">$100</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: use `padding`, `margin` just works for element `display: block;`

Comment: Try border-spacing:5em;

Comment: @Raja: If you want to comment on an answer, use the comment, not the edit button. Your edit got rejected

Answer (score 0):

One possibility is to add a class to your `tr` elements, that need that margin and define the rule in a .css file. However I would reccomend to set `padding-top`.

**CSS:**

```
tr.sample > td
{
  padding-bottom: 30px; <!--or padding-top -->
}
```

**Html:**

```
<tr class="sample">
    <td>January</td>
    <td>$100</td>
</tr>
<tr class="sample">
     //....
</tr>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer i have tried with the provided solution like below code snippet but it did not working from our end

Comment: <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

    <style type="text/css">
        .sample {
            padding-top:30px;
        }
    </style>

<table border="1" >
  <tr class="sample">
    <th>Month</th>
    <th>Savings</th>
  </tr>
  <tr >
    <td >January</td>
    <td >$100</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>February</td>
    <td>$80</td>
  </tr>
</table>

</body>
</html>

Comment: this is working fine. You just forget to add the class to ALL `tr` elements. Check your code and refer to this: http://jsfiddle.net/6qqjP/1/

Answer (score 0):

The [`margin`](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html#propdef-margin) properties do not apply to table rows or table cells.

The conclusions depend on why you would use them. To create just empty space above cell contents, you can use `padding-top`, but padding is different from margin – e.g., the top border of the cell would appear above its top padding.